# Performing a fit with training data for regression and predicting a value

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I am not familiar with ML background. Thus have this simple question.
Suppose I have training data for my dependent variable which depends on say 3 independent variables. Suppose I use some regression method and perform a fit according to that model on my training data.

Suppose now I pass independent variables from testing data and see the predicted value of my dependent variable.

Now, my question is, when I perform this non-parametric fit, what type of function gets stored or what actually happens such now when I supply some testing data, it predicts almost actual value.

Like, if I say, I perform a polynomial fit. I know that it is a line y = mx + c something and thus on giving x, I can predict y. And here the value of m and c gets derived from the training data. So now what type of function or parameters are involved in non-parametric fit?

Also, if I use scikit-learn, is there a method to see the values of these parameters derived from training data fit?

Comment: What does the documentation say for the specific scikit-learn functions you intend to use?

Comment: Well, this was a general question. However, I am planning to use quantile regression in specific and all that it mentions is that you perform a non parametric fit to predict the value using predict(X) function...

Comment: Also, what  I understood is that, for quantile regression, by performing a fit, we actually determine the so-called quantile distribution function, if I am not mistaken?

Comment: What is stored will depend on what kind of nls fit you are using.